# JQuery validate question

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery validate and calling a javascript method on the onclick event. But even when the validation fails, it still calls this method.  How do I check within the method if the validation failed, so that I can prevent this code from running?

```
<button id="btnSave" name="btnSave" runat="server" type="submit" onclick="addUser()" style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;" >Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [this is the plugin you're using](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryvalidate), you could use the `onValid` and `onInvalid` callback functions of the plugin and hook in the desired behaviour there.

For example, remove the JS from your HTML:

```
<button id="btnSave" name="btnSave" runat="server" type="submit" style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;" >Save</button>
```

and change the call to the plugin to something like

```
$("#btnSave").validate({onValid:addUser});
```

If you're using some other validation plugin, check the documentation - any good plugin will provide similar hooks that you can use.